# Chef Recipe to define kafka broker from attribute.

Tags: chef-infra, apache-kafka, chef-recipe

I need to spilt hostname and atrribute and set kafka broker id

hostname will  be like this kafka001, kafka0030.

so i am trying set the number value from the hostname and set as broker id for kafka.

if node['hostname']
  <<
end

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking, could you please try to rephrase the question?

Comment: Something along the line `node['hostname'][/\d+/].to_i` ?